# Delete lines from a file

Tags: shell-script

I have a file where data is present in below format :

```
cat file.txt
02|123
04|321
08|453
09|364
01|789
23|765
```

so here 02,04 ... represents Hour and 123,321 ... represents some random value.

I want to delete all the lines from this file where first two value is less than the current hour which will get from `date +'%H'`.

Suppose current hour is 10 so i want to delete lines containing first two less than 10 i.e

```
02|123
04|321
08|453
09|364
01|789
```

Comment: You want this in a script?

Comment: yes. need logic how to do this simply.

Comment: you can modify the answer for [THIS QUESTION](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27785471/remove-lines-where-values-are-less-than-a-constant-in-a-column) to suit your needs. Just use `awk -F "|"` to specify your field delimiter and compare the `$1` to the current hour as in that answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
HOUR=`date +%H`
awk -v hour=$HOUR -F"|" '{if($1 >= hour)print}' file.txt > newfile.txt
mv newfile.txt file.txt
```

Comment: You could simplify that to `awk -v hour=10 -F"|" '$1 >= hour' ...` (since `print` is awk's default action)